# Check wifi connection without actually connecting to the wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, vnc, raspberry-pi

I am trying to switch Wi-Fi from a headless pi over tightvnc viewer but want to make sure that my connection settings are correct without risking losing my current connection.

Lets say I am currently connected to Wifi-SSID="Apple" and I wanted to connect to Wifi-SSID="Orange".

Orange is WPA2 and I have the passphrase but want to make sure that the connection succeeds.

I'm using TightVNC to connect to my pi

I tried WPA_GUI - entered Orange's SSID and passphrase and the VNC connection was lost.

Comment: Interesting question. I guess, based on [this answer](http://serverfault.com/a/192152/145512) "you can create multiple wlan interfaces based on the physical interface, then connect them to various APs". This should give you possibility to establish connection to second wireless network without interrupting your first connection.

Comment: Thanks - I should mention that I am on LINUX Raspbian Jessie. Will creating a wlan1 mess up any original configs ? I tried installing network-manager for this purpose and totally hijacked my network adapters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can associate to multiple SSIDs at the same time. Instead, either get a second wifi adapter, or tell your Pi to connect to the new network, and connect back to the old one after some timeout if it didn't work.
Depends on your network setup how to do that.